# Silverligh 5 SDK RC + Async CTP : make it work

Tags: task-parallel-library, parallel-extensions, silverlight-5.0, async-await

Just installed the Silverligh 5 SDK RC. There is a problem using it inside a project that uses the Async CTP.

Both AsyncCtpLibrary_Silverlight.dll and mscorlib.dll contains the Task type (And some other Task related types) that is sitting in the exact same namespace.

Here is the error msg:
[image]

So to solve this ambiguity I changed the Alias on the AsyncCtpLibrary_Silverlight.dll to "AsyncCtp". And then changed the cs file accordingly:

```
    extern alias AsyncCtp;
    using AsyncCtp::System.Threading.Tasks;
    using AsyncCtp::System.Threading;
```

This seems to solve the ambiguity problem, but now the "async" keyword is not recognized. These are the related errors:
[image]

[image]

Is there a way around it, or is it a dead end ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way around it would be to recompile the AsyncCtpLibrary_Silverlight.dll and remove all the TPL types from there. But I wouldn't bother... Check out the announcement at the Async CTP [forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/async/threads):

> We are working on an update of the Async CTP. This will:
>
> - Address installation issues, where the current Async CTP can no
>     longer be installed onto a fully-patched VS2010 SP1;
> - **Provide compatibility with Silverlight 5;**
> - Provide compatibility with background agents in Windows Phone
>     apps.
>
> We are working on this now, and will post the release here as soon as
>   it’s available.

**Update:** Async CTP v3 was released with Silverlight 5 support: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/11/01/10232099.aspx